# How can I get the memory address of a JavaScript variable?

Tags: javascript, spidermonkey, memory-address

Is it possible to find the memory address of a JavaScript variable?  The JavaScript code is part of (embedded into) a normal application where JavaScript is used as a front end to C++ and does not run on the browser. The JavaScript implementation used is SpiderMonkey.

Comment: By "embedded into a normal application", do you mean you have a web page with embedded Javascript?

Comment: No, it does not run on the browser, there are no web pages involved. The JavaScript engine is part of a normal desktop app.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If it would be possible at all, it would be very dependent on the javascript engine. The more modern javascript engine compile their code using a just in time compiler and messing with their internal variables would be either bad for performance, or bad for stability.

If the engine allows it, why not make a function call interface to some native code to exchange the variable's values?

Comment: Yes I agree, think need to have some code in C++ which can interface with JavaScript.

Answer (score 15):

It's more or less impossible - Javascript's evaluation strategy is to always use call by value, but in the case of Objects (including arrays) the value passed is a reference to the Object, which is not copied or cloned. If you reassign the Object itself in the function, the original won't be changed, but if you reassign one of the Object's properties, that will affect the original Object.

That said, what are you trying to accomplish? If it's just passing complex data between C++ and Javascript, you could use a JSON library to communicate. Send a JSON object to C++ for processing, and get a JSON object to replace the old one.

Comment: Great note about reassigning Object itself or a property. Can you somehow change the Object the original points to?

Comment: Do you mean, change the reference of an object within a different scope? No. In such situations it's best to make use of JS's encapsulation or object-oriented facilities, either by putting the function body and the reference you want to change in the same scope, or by making the reference and the function members of the same object.

Answer (score 4):

You can using a ***side-channel***, but you can't do anything useful with it other than attacking browser security!

The closest to virtual addresses are ArrayBuffers.

If one virtual address within an ArrayBuffer is identified,
the remaining addresses are also known, as both the addresses
of the memory and the array indices are linear.

Although virtual addresses are not themselves physical memory addresses, there are ways to translate virtual address into a physical memory address.

Browser engines allocate ArrayBuffers always page
aligned. The first byte of the ArrayBuffer is therefore at the
beginning of a new physical page and has the least significant
12 bits set to ‘0’.

If a large chunk of memory is allocated, browser engines typically
use mmap to allocate this memory, which is optimized to
allocate 2 MB transparent huge pages (THP) instead of 4 KB
pages.

As these physical pages are mapped on
demand, i.e., as soon as the first access to the page occurs,
iterating over the array indices results in page faults at the
beginning of a new page. The time to resolve a page fault is
significantly higher than a normal memory access. Thus, you can knows the index at which a new 2 MB page starts. At
this array index, the underlying physical page has the 21 least
significant bits set to ‘0’.

This answer is not trying to provide a proof of concept because I don’t have time for this, but I may be able to do so in the future. This answer is an attempt to point the right direction to the person asking the question.

Sources,

http://www.misc0110.net/files/jszero.pdf

https://download.vusec.net/papers/anc_ndss17.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I think it's possible, but you'd have to:

1. download the node.js source code.
2. add in your function manually (like returning the memory address of a pointer, etc.)
3. compile it and use it as your node executable.

Comment: is it your assumption?