# extracting strings from JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, c++, spidermonkey

Using embedded SpiderMonkey in my C++ application I would like to extract all the strings from JavaScript code. JavaScript code looks something like this:

```
var foo = "something";  
var space = " ";  
var bar = foo + space + "beautiful";
```

C++ code looks like this:

```
char *script = "var foo = \"something\"; var space = \" \"; var bar = foo + space + \"beautiful\";";
ok = JS_EvaluateScript(cx, global, script, strlen(script), filename, lineno, &rval);
```

So my questions is, after SpiderMonkey executes JavaScript, how can I extract the string from variable **bar** (extracted value should be "something beautiful") and use it in my regular C++ code? I guess I have to evaluate the script first and then somehow extract the string from the JavaScript variable. I don't know how to extract the string using SpiderMonkey.

My second question:
http://siliconforks.com/doc/parsing-javascript-with-spidermonkey/
This SpiderMonkey JavaScript parser is written for SpiderMonkey 1.6. 
How can this be done with latest SpiderMonkey, because APIs for 
parsing have changed?

Thnx in advance,
Goran

Comment: Please be more clear on the context in which you need to extract. If you are talking about passing content of client-side JS variables to server side C++ you need to send the vars to the server using http (ajax, form)

Comment: @mplungjan I wasn't very precise. I have embedded SpiderMonkey in my C++ app. Short snippet: char *script = "var foo = 'some string'"; ok = JS_EvaluateScript(cx, global, script, strlen(script), filename, lineno, &rval); How can I now get to the value of JavaScript variable foo?

Comment: @mplungjan Updated. Do You know to solve my problem? Maybe You can give me some directions so I can investigate further? Thank You.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/639514/how-can-i-get-the-memory-address-of-a-javascript-variable
More here: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=spidermonkey+[c%2B%2B]+javascript+variable&submit=search
I have no idea myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since **bar** is property of global object, after the JS_EvaluateScript() I can use JS_GetProperty() function, something like this

```
JS_GetProperty(cx, global, "bar", &rval);
JSString *str = JS_ValueToString(cx, rval);
printf("%s\n", JS_EncodeString(cx, str));
```

Comment: The above example NO LONGER WORKS with the latest Mozilla JavaScript version 38 or newer (both `js` and `xpcshell`)

Answer (score -1):

Check String operation functions like subString. It can be used to resolve your query.

Comment: substring. Not subString - and I doubt that is what he needs.