# Function identity in javascript

Tags: javascript

The following is unintuitive behavior in javascript,

```
function function1 () {};
function function2 () {};

var class_a_functions = {function1:true, function2:true};
var contained = function1 in class_a_functions;//false
var equals = function1.name in class_a_functions;//true
```

Why does the `in` containment test fail even though I have inserted the functions, not their names, into the dictionary?

EDIT:
If it isn't obvious, I am aware that function1.name is "function1". This is why I asked why the test fails "even though I have inserted the functions, not their names".

Comment: that is `function` not `fuction`?

Comment: should be var contained = 'function1' in class_a_functions; or  contained = function1.name in class_a_function

Comment: that's exactly why I am asking the question. also note that function.name isn't supported in IE.

Comment: You can't use a function as an object key (if that's what you're trying to illustrate).  Object keys are strings only.  There is an object that lets you keep track of a set of other objects (which could be functions too) here: https://github.com/jfriend00/Javascript-Set.  It does that by automatically coining a unique string as a key property for each object and using that key in the ObjectSet.

Comment: You haven't "inserted the functions".  First, unlike python, in JS `{ key: value }` syntax treats `key` as literal "key".  You'd need `{ [function1]: true }` syntax for a dynamic key. BUT JS objects coerce all keys to strings anyway!  Play with `[ function1, function2 ]` for a container actually holding functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in

```
// Arrays
var trees = new Array("redwood", "bay", "cedar", "oak", "maple");
0 in trees        // returns true
3 in trees        // returns true
6 in trees        // returns false cause there's no 6th key in trees Array
"bay" in trees    // returns false (you must specify the 
                  // index number, not the value at that index)
"length" in trees // returns true (length is an Array property)
```

That's why it returns `false`

On the other case, `class_a_functions[0]` is the reference to the stored function in Array that's why equality returns `true` cause `fn1() === fn1()`

---

Now after your edited question the above seems like nonsense so I'll answer further:

```
var class_a_functions = {function1:true, function2:true};
```

**Is now and object** where `function1` and `function2` are simple Properties holding `true` as Value.

---

```
var contained = function1 in class_a_functions;//false
```

The above returns `false` cause there's no "function1" Function inside the Object reference `class_a_functions`

---

```
var equals = function1.name in class_a_functions;//true
```

The above... well, let's go back to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in), says:

```
Summary:
The in operator returns true if the specified property
is in the specified object.
```

So you have a property of `function1` Now let's see if is present in the Object `class_a_functions` ... Yes. So **TRUE**

Comment: @erjoalgo - He's showing that `in` applies to array indexes, not to contents of the array.  A few more words of text would improve the answer.

Comment: Ok. I need to rephrase the question then, sorry

Comment: This has a lot to do with the question. First read the linked Document then notice how `IN` is actually working

Comment: ok. So I was the one to make the mistake, thinking that I could describe the problem more simply with an array instead of a dictionary.

Comment: I see. Is there a way to have something like a set of objects by object id or memory location in javascript?

Comment: @erjoalgo - here's an ObjectSet if that's really what you're looking for: https://github.com/jfriend00/Javascript-Set

Comment: I accepted your question. But most of your commentary is trivial and restates information that the OP (I) evidently already knows.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why most of the answers are so trivial and don't really address the underlying issue motivating the question, which is that getting the memory address/object hash/object id  in javascipt is "impossible", and therefore the equality testing by object reference is also "impossible".

[How can I get the memory address of a JavaScript variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/639514/how-can-i-get-the-memory-address-of-a-javascript-variable)

A solution for that containment problem is to monkey-patch an object to contain a unique property/string that can be used as a key.

Comment: If you believe your answer is the best one here, you should accept your own answer instead.

Answer (score 0):

The `in` is used to identify the key not the value.

Answer (score 0):

The `in` operator tests if a property is in an object. `function1` is not a property of the array, it's a member.

Answer (score 0):

There should be

```
'function1' in class_a_functions;//true
```

This is because

In a dictionary

```
obj = {key:5}
```

this is equal to

```
obj = {"key":5} // so it will be stored as string
```

If you will see the docs it says `prop` is **A string or numeric expression representing a property name or array index.**