# How to detect that an array is replaced by an identical other array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, debugging

In my code, I have a variable containing an array. I want to debug manipulations of that variable. I do not mind if the contents of the array are changing, but I have to see how often and when the array itself changes.

An example:

```
window.myarray = []
console.log(window.myarray); // outputs: []

window.myarray.push("bla"); // an irrelevant manipulation
console.log(window.myarray); // outputs: ["bla"]

window.myarray = ["bla"]; // a change of the array's identity!
console.log(window.myarray); // still outputs: ["bla"]
```

How can I detect, that the array that is stored in a variable has changed, even if the content of the old and new arrays are the same?

Comment: Store a temporary reference to `window.myarray`'s state you want to detect it changing from. E.g `tmp = window.myarray`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You check the identity like this:

```js
window.myarray = []
var backup = window.myarray;

window.myarray.push("bla"); // an irrelevant manipulation
console.log(backup === window.myarray); // true

window.myarray = ["bla"]; // a change of the array's identity!
console.log(backup === window.myarray); // false
```

Note that `backup` isn't an actual copy, just a reference to the same in-memory object.

Comment: This is already helpful, but I would prefer to be able to compare it in the console log.

Comment: @slartidan I don't understand what you mean by that, at all.

Comment: I would like to output something in the console log, that uniquely identifies an instance of an array. So that I can check afterwards if two logged arrays are identical or not.

Comment: @slartidan I see; according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50530936/is-there-any-method-to-check-memory-address-of-javascript-variable) there's no way to grab the memory address like for instance Java prints as default `toString()`.

Answer (score 5):

You could use proxies

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy

Or you can define a property on window

```js
(function() {
  let _myArray;
  Object.defineProperty(window, "myArray", {
    set(value) {
      _myArray = value;
      console.log('changed', value);
    },
    get() {
      return _myArray
    }
  })
}())

window.myArray = [];

window.myArray = ['bar'];
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty

Comment: `console.error` would be slightly better as it includes the stack trace.