# Javascript Object property value when reassign the object

Tags: javascript

```js
var cat = { name: 'Athena' };

function swap(feline) {
  feline.name = 'Wild';
  feline = { name: 'Tabby' };
}

swap(cat);
console.log(cat.name);
```

Can Anyone explain why cat.name showing "Wild" because I've again assigned the `feline = {name:'Tabby'}`

Comment: This might helpful to you [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language#:~:text=JavaScript%20always%20evaluates%20each%20expression,by%20reference%22%20language%2C%20however.)

Comment: In the first line, feline was just a reference to cat. Since objects are passed by reference changing feline updates cat. On the second line, you are reassigning the feline object with another object. This doesn't update the original cat object.

Comment: [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50530975/12146581)

Answer (score 1):

in here you have two variables

1. cat
2. feline

so when you are passing the cat to swap function, actually you passing reference to cat variable, that is address of cat variable. because of this feline will point to original object of cat. so when you change feline.name, you are actually changing cat

then you are assigning another variable that is
`feline = { name: 'Tabby' };`
by doing this now feline variable is no longer pointing to same cat object, so cat object which have name 'wild' will be logged

Answer (score 1):

When you pass `cat` as a parameter to the `swap` function, you are giving the reference to the `cat` variable. So now `feline` points to the same reference as `cat`. Both are looking at the same object through reference.

```
feline.name = 'Wild'
```

`feline` changes the name of the object it is referencing. Since the variable `cat` also looks at the object in this reference, it will display 'Wild' when it reaches the name via `cat`.

```
feline = { name: 'Tabby' }
```

Where you assign a new object, a new reference to the `feline` variable. So it no longer looks at the reference the `cat` variable is looking at. In short, `cat` is unaffected.

I tried to summarize very briefly without going into details.